# Formatting integer to currency without rounding it up

Tags: java, string

I learning java and I am trying to learn conversion to currency format.

```
String amount = "1234567.89"
amount = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US")).format(Float.parseFloat(amount);
```

But the output for this becomes

```
$1,234,568.00
```

I don't want the value to round up and the output to be

```
$1,234,567.89
```

Not sure how to do it.

Comment: Just to pick a nit, and I don't see it as the root of the problem, but `"1234567.89"` ain't *an integer which is in string format*.

Comment: I changed it to Double.parseDouble and it worked somehow

Comment: I strongly recommend you to ***not*** use `float` or `double` for currency, as this tends to be inaccurate at times.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US")).format(new BigDecimal(amount));
```